# How to upload multiple files with cloudinary and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I've been looking for a while at the [Cloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem) documentation but can't figure out how to upload multiple files to it using Rails and a html form.

I added Cloudinary support to my Carrierwave `ImageUploader`

```
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
```

and I added my api-key and secret to `config/cloudinary.yml`

but what more do I need to change? For now, I kept everything as it was with carrierwave. So my form holds a file field

```
<%=file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

and then for every image a new `picture` instance gets created, and every picture instance holds a `:image` attribute

```
if params[:images]
     params[:images].each do |image|
           @post.pictures.create(image: image)
     end
end
```

I kept my `ImageUploader` more or less default.

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end 
end
```

When I upload some images, the urls are linking to a cloudinary page, but nothing has been actually uploaded to cloudinary. Can I just add something to the `create` action of the `picture` controller to actually upload the image? Something like

```
def create
   @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)  
   @picture.save
   Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(picture_params)
end
```

Comment: The line of code where you upload your images would be good to see. You should have something like this: `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(your_image, auth)`

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my question, but this line doesn't seem to upload it either

Comment: You need to define your authorization params, that are needed for `.upload` as a second parameter. You should do that, and use `.upload` where you actually `include Cloudinary::CarrierWave`

Comment: With authorization, do you mean the api key and secret? because that's defined in `config/cloudinary.yml`, so that should be allright. Also, I should I add the `.upload` to my `ImageUploader` then?

Comment: Yes and yes - this sounds reasonable. feel free to also post some relevant parts of your uploader instead of your file field, which looks fine to me.

Comment: I edited my last post, and added the uploader details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89141/discussion-between-sjbuysse-and-the-f).

Comment: Try using `create!` instead to raise an exception on any errors. Currently they are silently ignored. I'm not as familiar with CarrierWave as Paperclip, but why do you have `storage :file`? In Paperclip, you have to indicate `:storage => :cloudinary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the value of `image`, you could do this:

```
if params[:images]
  params[:images].each do |image|
    @post.pictures.create(image: image)
  end
  upload_images(@post.pictures)
end

def upload_images(images)
  images.each do |i|
    Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(i)
  end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, here is the contents of `images` when I upload just 1 image. `"images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f330c224f48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150909-4201-1j1o465.JPG>, @original_filename="DSC00699.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images[]\"; filename=\"DSC00699.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]`

Comment: have you tried upload `image.tempfile` or `image.original_filename` instead of just `image`. Remember, you want to upload the file, not the image object.

Comment: I played around a bit, and it's working more or less with this code now. Thanks for all the help The F. I do have one more problem, and that's that the public_id's don't match, but I created a new question for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493427/public-id-doesnt-match-between-cloudinary-and-carrierwave

Comment: There is no need to upload the image manually to Cloudinary. The each loop should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's done in Paperclip.

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  if Rails.env == 'production'
    has_attached_file :file, :storage => :cloudinary, :path => ':class/:id/:filename', :cloudinary_resource_type => :raw


class Deal < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :attachments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  def files=(files)
    files.each do |file|
      attachments.build(file: file)
    end
  end

#controller
def deal_params
  params.require(:deal).permit :name, ...,  photos: [], files: [] 

#view
= form_for([parent, child], html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
  =f.file_field :files, multiple: true, class: 'form-control'
```