# public_id doesn't match between cloudinary and carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I'm using CarrierWave and Cloudinary to upload multiple pictures to my blogposts. I upload them from my browser.
This happens with the use of a file field in the `post` form.

```
<%=file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

When the form is being submitted, a `picture` instance is created for each one of the images and the image is being uploaded to Cloudinary.

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        if params[:images]
            params[:images].each do |image|
                @post.pictures.create(image: image)
                Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(image)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The ImageUploader I use is almost default (exept for including the cloudinary plugin)

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end 
end
```

Now, the image is being saved to my server, and the image is being uploaded to cloudinary. But somehow the `public_id's` never match. Does anyone understand why not? Is there a new `public_id` created when I call `Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(image)`?

Answer (score 2):

After checking the project that Tal Lev-Ami (thanks a lot for this!) refered me to, I figured out that the problem with my ImageUploader was the line

```
storage :file
```

After commenting out this line, everything worked perfectly (and I don't have to manually upload my images). If anyone understands why this line was causing the problem, be my guest to post it here for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to manually upload the image to Cloudinary. When using the CarrierWave uploader, the image will get automatically uploaded to Cloudinary and public_id updated in the model.

Comment: Mine doesn't do that though... It automatically creates a cloudinary URL, yes. But no uploading. Then when I upload it manually, the link doesn't match.

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord? Is the picture object saved successfully? Are you sure it's not uploaded? (notice that store_dir has no effect when cloudinary is used).

Comment: I am using ActiveRecord, the picture object is saved successfully to the server, because when I just don't include the Cloudinary plugin in the ImageUploader everything works fine. And I'm sure it's not uploaded, because when I go to my cloudinary account there are no pictures unless I upload them manually with the `.upload()` method.

Comment: Can you see if the following sample project is working for you? https://github.com/taragano/Cloudinary_multiple_uploads/
To set it up - git clone the project, run bundle, copy you cloudinary.yml to the config directory and run rake db:migrate

Comment: It worked, and made me figure out what was wrong. See my answer